Windows Bluetooth 5.x extended advertisment support?
I have some .net tooling for my embedded devices. I am performing a systems update on them at the moment and would like to start using extended advertising for the payload size increase. I have a TP-Link UB500 dongle that I use from my windows11 machine to fascilitate the tooling. I have just updated to the latest driver version from the tp link website and it is now showing up as a 5.3 adapter. Here's where the problems start.
I am using the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher object from Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement. This works for my legacy project but when I set AllowExtendedAdvertisements to true I do not see my extended advertisement device. I am using a nrf52840 ble sniffer in wireshark to confirm that the device is advertising. I set up a little hook in the receiver to tell if I ever see my device, but I don't.
watcher.Received += (BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.AdvertisementType == BluetoothLEAdvertisementType.Extended || (eventArgs.BluetoothAddress == targetAddress))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found extended packet?");
    }
}

In device manager under Properties>details>"Bluetooth radio supports Advertising Extensions" the option is false. Additionally when I run the following it shows as false.
var ba = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
Console.WriteLine(ba.IsExtendedAdvertisingSupported);

So is there some windows options to enable this feature given that the driver indicates the adapter is 5.3 which surely supports this feature by now? Am I misunderstanding the usages of
AllowExtendedAdvertisements?

Did you actually check (e.g. with TP-Link or on the datasheet etc.) that your bluetooth adapter actually supports extended advertisement or are you assuming it does? My guess is, if Windows says it doesn't support it, then it doesn't support it.

The Bluetooth version says nothing about which features are supported, since every new feature added in the Bluetooth spec is almost always optional to implement. The only thing the version tells you is which features may be supported.

In addition to the previous writers, the BluetoothAdapter class supports many properties that provide information about which function the adapter supports.

I really did just expect it since it's 5.3 and should be pretty.mature. I suppose consumer grade wouldn't particularly care about this sort of thing. I can't find ub500 say it does or doesn't support it. Any suggestions that you know will?

Are you sure that with var ba = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync() you are getting your USB Bluetooth dongle and not an adapter that was already built into the PC (as is the case with 100% of today's laptops, for example)?

@Risto fairly confident. Device manager shows only one adapted. It's a PC and afaik there's no on board
